# Use of deallocator & allocator in shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am using few library functions that return a pointer created either using malloc or new.
So, I have my own customer deallocator based on what type of allocation was used.

E.g

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr1(LibFunctA(), &MallocDeleter); //LibFunctA returns pointer created using malloc
shared_ptr<int> ptr2(LibFunctB(), &newDeleter);  //LibFunctB returns pointer created using new
```

Now, I understand this is a very naive use of deallocator above but what other scenarios is it heavily used for ?

Also, how can one use a customer allocator ? I tried to assign a custom allocator as below but now how do I actually get it called ? Where does this kind of feature help ?

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr3(nullptr_t, &CustomDeleter, &CustomAllocator);  //assume both functs are defined somewhere.
```

Comment: Here are [some more ideas](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h).

Comment: Possibly related: [Boost shared_ptr: How how to use custom deleters and allocators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3378621/33732).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything "naive" about using deleters that way. It is the main purpose of the feature after all; to destroy pointer objects that aren't allocated using the standard C++ methods.

Allocators are for when you need control of how the `shared_ptr`'s control block of memory is allocated and deleted. For example, you might have a pool of memory that you want these things to come from, or if you're in a memory-limited situation where allocation of memory via `new` is simply not acceptable. And since the type of the control block is up to `shared_ptr`, there's no other way to be able to control how it is allocated except with some kind of allocator.

Comment: In the above e.g how do I actually get ptr3 to point to a newly allocated block ? I couldnt find any way to get CustomAllocator Function invoked. Is there any working example of Allocator ?

Comment: @FrankQ.: Why would it invoke a custom allocator? You gave it a NULL pointer; it's not being told to store anything. And since it isn't storing anything, it's not allocating anything with the allocator either. Nor is it going to delete anything with the deleter.

Answer (score 3):

Custom deleters for `shared_ptr` are very useful for wrapping some (usually) C resource that you need to later call a freeing function on. For example, you might do something like:

```
shared_ptr<void> file(::CreateFileW(...), ::CloseHandle);
```

Examples like this abound in C libraries. This saves from having to manually free the resource later and take care of possible exceptions and other nasties.

Answer (score 1):

I think the custom allocator will be used to allocate space for the "shared count" object, that stores a copy of the deallocator (deleter) and the reference counter.

As for what a custom deleter can be used for...

One use was already mentioned: make `shared_ptr` compatible with objects that must be deleted by some special function (like `FILE` which is deleted by `fclose`), without having to wrap it into a helper-class that takes care of the proper deletion.

Another use for a custom deleter is pools. The pool can hand out `shared_ptr<T>` that were initialized with a "special" deleter, which doesn't really delete anything, but returns the object to the pool instead.

And one other thing: the deleter is already necessary to implement some `shared_ptr` features. E.g. the type that's deleted is always fixed at creation time, and independent of the type of the `shared_ptr` that's being initialized.

Vou can create a `shared_ptr<Base>` by actually initializing it with a `Derived`. `shared_ptr` guarantees that when the object is deleted, it will be deleted as a `Derived`, even if `Base` does *not* have a virtual dtor. To make this possible, `shared_ptr` already has to store some information about how the object shall be deleted. So allowing the user to specify a completely custom deleter doesn't cost anything (in terms of runtime performance), and doesn't require much additional code either.

There are probably dozens of other scenarios where one can make good use of the custom deleter, that's just what I have come up with so far.