# Do I need custom allocators for shared pointers?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr

If I override operator new and operator delete (or passing a custom deleter), what use is passing an allocator? Will the shared_ptr at some other time than construction and deconstruction do allocations and deallocations?

Comment: Isn't it true that if you provided a memory pool for your program that you'd need an allocation and perhaps you would provide, then, an allocator? IOW, if I manage my own memory, for what ever reason, I would want the system to "allocate" the memory as I see fit, i.e., not grab lots of unneeded space as what happens, if I'm not mistaken, unfortunately for some situations.

Comment: I'll be writing an allocator anyway, since it is needed for containers. What I'm asking here is just why an allocator is needed for shared_ptr, since a pointer to allocated memory is already passed to the constructor. Should I expect shared_ptrs to allocate stuff on their own behind the scenes?

Comment: I might be careful about saying the allocator is needed for containers in general. The standard, as I've read it, allows for allocators but isn't required as you say. A `queue` is amongst the container classes but does not require that an allocator be provided.

Comment: Naturally. I meant to say that it is needed for the containers we'll be using. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allocator passed into a boost::shared_ptr is used to allocate the internal details of the shared pointer (The shared/weak reference counts) and has nothing to do with the object passed in, which you will have already allocated, as you pointed out.

Here is another answer on the subject:
[Boost shared_ptr: How to use custom deleters and allocators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378621/boost-shared-ptr-how-to-use-custom-deleters-and-allocators)